# Karma Jasmine unit test issue in angular 7 - cannot read property 'success' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am having problem in running ng test using Karma and Jasmine. It stops the browser and when I cancel the run then it throws the below error.

```
> Cannot read property 'success' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'success' of undefined
>     at TestCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\workspace\uif_mdm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\packages\angular\cli\models\architect-command.ts:242:21)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Please show what you were testing?

Comment: Possibly addressed here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3267

Answer (score 0):

This error was gone when I uninstalled karma-phantomjs-launcher. Also had to remove
browsers: ['PhantomJs'] in karma.conf.js and add below instead

```
 browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
      base: 'ChromeHeadless',
      flags: ['--no-sandbox']
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When a ran the unit test with `ng test` this error was thrown. When a ran the unit test with npm run test (test script being `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage`) it ran successfully.

Adding flag `--watch=false` on `ng test` fixed for me.